# Need Help on curl http header using AFNetworking

Tags: ios6, authorization, afnetworking

I have trouble attach curl header authorization with accesstoken something like this :

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: AccessToken xxxxxxx"
```

I have tried using this following :

```
NSString *baseurl = @"http://localhost.com:9000";
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseurl]];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"xxxxxxxxx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:@"ios/posts"
                                                  parameters:nil];
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the code of [AFHTTPClient](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L422-L424) that when you call `setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken` all it's actually doing is calling `setDefaultHeader:value` with some predefined values. Your desired format doesn't look like it lines up with those values. What you'll probably need to do is something like this:

```
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AccessToken %@", @"xxxxxxx"]];
```